# How to extract @media print from main.css file without need for seperate print.css file

Tags: javascript, css, sass, printing, blazor

Before going forward I first want to clarify. is this a bad practice to go down? what are the pros and cons of having @media print in with your main.css file and not on a seperate print.css file.

On past projects I have had to duplicate whole sections of css transferring to a seperate print.css file so that when the browser client was selected to print the page overview only hand picked sections that were customized for printing would be sent to the print stack. this was achieved by adding print hidden tags to headers etc and seemed really messy.

A similar question around this is here.

[Is there a way to use the same CSS stylesheet for print media and the default layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185663/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-same-css-stylesheet-for-print-media-and-the-default-la)

Is there an easier way to do this? without having to duplicate css?
it seems that due to the folder layout of the wwwroot folder if there isn't a print.css file compiled the @media print css points are not implemented. although they are still contained within the css.min file

Any help with this is appreciated!

thanks !
//Edit

I have a snippet like so of my css style sheet.

```
.ContainerHeader {
 
    .thisisincludedclass {
        display: none;
    }
    //@media redirects a source code for css with the same classes to the same section.
    @media print {
        .ContainerHeader {
            display: none !important;
        }

        .ContainerPageContent {
            display: none !important;
        }

        .thisIsThePrintClass {
            display: none;
        }
    }
```

yet the html sections with those class attributes are still displayed. I am finding the only way this works is if i export the classes to an entirely seperate print.css file and compile to the wwwroot folder the print.css file seperately. otherwise based on the @media tags no print.css file is created.

Comment: Some useful threads I have found around this topic are located here. https://www.reddit.com/r/Blazor/comments/qw9a0m/best_approach_for_printing_a_blazor_page/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by pointing your style link for media printing to the same css file you have your main layout in and adding @media print tags to it. I am not sure though if this is best practice.

```
<link href="css/main.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/main.min.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Now you can have @media tags for print styling within the main css file. like below

```
.ContainerHeader {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    background-image: url(/images/header.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    grid-area: ContainerHeader;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 99;

    @media print {
        .ContainerHeader{
            display:none !important;
        }
    }
}
```